Why does an occurrence of line separator (U+2028) break the search/select functionality?
A few weeks ago I was in the situation where the program successfully selected all lines that matched a regular expression, but did not select one particular (also matching) line. I checked the correctness of my regex (it was correct), then tried again. The result was the same: that line was not selected, as if it did not match the regex, which was absolutely inexplicable because it obviously matched. I was really surprised and intrigued, and the only option was to check all characters of the line, one by one. I soon found the cause of the problem: it was a single occurrence of U+2028: Line separator. As soon as I deleted this character, the program was able to select the corresponding line.
In order to demonstrate the issue, suppose that I have the file that contains the following sequence of characters:

U+0061: Latin small letter A;
U+2028: Line separator;
U+0062: Latin small letter B;
U+002C: Comma;
U+0063: Latin small letter C;
U+2028: Line separator;
U+0064: Latin small letter D.

Question #1: why is this sequence displayed as one line without any indication of the presence of line separators? According to Table 5-1 in Section 5.8 of “The Unicode® Standard Version 15.0 – Core Specification”, line separators (and paragraph separators) are the newline characters. But if I go to Tools > Properties for All Configurations > Marks and make sure that the Show Newline Characters option is checked, all line separators remain invisible (they are displayed as characters with zero width).
Out of interest, I tested how the above seven-character sequence is displayed in various editors, and the results show that there is no consensus. Some display it as three lines. Some display it as one line where a line separator looks like a single space. Chromium (browser, in a textarea element) and Notepad (text editor in Windows) display it as one line where a line separator looks like a rectangle with dashed borders and the L SEP text inside. Firefox (browser, in a textarea element) displays it the same way as EmEditor: one line, no indication of line separators at all. I think that the Chromium/Notepad approach is a suitable solution that can be used by default.
But the next problem is much more significant. Suppose that I need to select all lines that contain at least one comma. Each line must be selected in its entirety, i.e. from the first character to the last one. So I go to Search > Find..., check Regular Expressions and add ^.*?,.*?$ or ^.*,.*$ as the regex. Then I go to Advanced... and make sure that the Regular Expression “.” Can Match Newline Characters option is unchecked. Then I click Select All. But nothing gets selected: the program writes 0 matches are found in 0 lines in the left bottom of the window. In addition, if I place the cursor at the beginning of the file and click Find Next (instead of Select All), the program finds the b,c part (which means that line separators are recognized as line boundaries) and highlights it with the rgb(0, 120, 215) background color for the selection, but does not highlight it with the rgb(64, 255, 64) background color for the search match! If the Count Matches option is checked, the program writes 0 matches are found in 0 lines in the left bottom of the window. Clearly, something is wrong here.
Question #2: why does an occurrence of line separator (U+2028) break the search/select functionality in such a way?
Note: the situation is the same for U+2028: Paragraph separator. Maybe there are other problematic characters (which I am not aware of) that unexpectedly break the search/select functionality.
EDIT
I changed the regular expression engine to Onigmo. This seems to solve the problem: now the program selects the entire line (from a to d) and highlights it correctly.

I can't reproduce the part where you put the cursor at the beginning of the file and click Find Next. It doesn't find any string and it says "Cannot find ^.?,.?$ anywhere in document." Same with Find Previous. This with with the default Advanced settings for Find. Please let me know which version of EmEditor you use. If you switch the engine to Onigmo, you will see that its behavior differs from Boost Regex.

@MakotoE: “It doesn't find any string” — how can it happen if the seven-character sequence that I have given obviously matches the regex? Did you make sure that the sequence you have is exactly that sequence (its visible length is 5, but the real length is 7)? How did you add line separators? As for me, I typed &#x2028; and converted it from the HTML entity to a Unicode character. I used different versions of the program (starting from version 21.6).

This is a quick update - we have reproduced the issue, and we are looking into it. Thank you for describing the issue.

A new update: A future version of EmEditor will fix the issue so that both Find and Select All will find the matching string. It was caused by Find and Select All using different regex flags in the internal code.
